# How can I have an SKSpriteNode follow the same path back and forth?

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

My code is compartmentalized over many files, so I hope I can describe this easily.
I have a CGMutablePath() that goes from point A to point B
I place an SKSpriteNode at point A and execute:

```
yourline0 = SKShapeNode()
pathToDraw0.move(to: cgPoints[0])
pathToDraw0.addQuadCurve(to: cgPoints[1], control: cgPoints[2])

yourline0.lineWidth = 0
yourline0.path = pathToDraw0
yourline0.strokeColor = .clear

iconPath0 = pathToDraw0

SKAction.follow(iconPath0, asOffset: false, orientToPath: false, duration: 1))
```

I execute that SKACtion and as I expected, my SKNode goes from point A to point B. Fine.

I'm not sure how to reverse it, I assumed from the dox that calling that same SKAction as is, would make the SKNode go from point B to A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method called reversed() which you could use.

Below I have given your action a name of "youraction"

```
            let youraction = SKAction.follow(iconPath0, asOffset: false, orientToPath: false, duration: 1)
            let reverseaction = SKAction.reversed(youraction)
            yourspritenode.run(reverseaction)
```

Alternatively, you can just use reversed after the action name to run it in reverse:

```
            yourspritenode.run(youraction.reversed())
```